# Массивы в JavaScript,не получается сделать задачи

Tags: javascript

Массив одномерный, числа вводятся рандомом в определенном диапазоне.

1. Дан массив целых чисел. Выяснить является ли p-й элемент массива положительным.

   Незнаю как запросить обрабутку определенного(индексированного элемента) с клавиатуры что бы его проверял на положительность в данный момент выводиит все положительные числа находящиеся в массиве.

   ```
   <form name="numbers">
   <input type="text" name="age">
   <input type="button" value="Расчет" onclick="calculate( );">
   </form>

   <script language="JavaScript">
   function calculate( ) {
   n=document.numbers.age.value;
   //n=Number(n);
   var a = new Array(n);
   //var a = [];
   for (i=0; i<n; i++){
       a[i] = Math.round(Math.random()*120-20);
       document.write(a[i]+"<br>");
   }
   function condition(value, index, array) {

       var result = false;
       if (value >0) {
           result = true;
       }
       //else {
       //alert('Error');
       //}

      return result;
   };
   var filteredA = a.filter(condition);

   for(var i=0; i < filteredA.length; i++)
      document.write(' POlozh Chisla Massiva A ->'+filteredA[i] + "<br/>");

   }

   </script>
   ```
2. Дан массив целых чисел. Напечатать все четные элементы. Зацикливает в ответе русскоязычный текст,в целом работает но вот зацикливание ответе не нравится. ' Chrtnie Chisla Massiva A ->' пишет рядом с каждым числом,нужно что бы аисалось 1 раз а ниже четные числа. Недогоняю как исправить.

   ```
   <form name="numbers">
   <input type="text" name="age">
   <input type="button" value="Расчет" onclick="calculate( );">
   </form>
   <script language="JavaScript">
   function calculate( ) {
   n=document.numbers.age.value;
   //n=Number(n);
   var a = new Array(n);
   //var a = [];
   for (i=0; i<n; i++){
       a[i] = Math.round(Math.random()*120-20);
       document.write(a[i]+"<br>");
   }
   function condition(value, index, array) {
       var result = false;
       if (value %2 == 0) {
           result = true;
       }
       //else {
       //alert('Error');
       //}
      return result;
   };
   var filteredA = a.filter(condition);
   for(var i=0; i < filteredA.length; i++)
      document.write(' Chrtnie Chisla Massiva A ->'+filteredA[i] + "<br/>"); 
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: здесь не решают задачи за вас. Покажите, что сделали вы сами.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как удаленный автором

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста.

```js
var arr = [-1, 3, -5, 6, 7, -10];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) if (arr[i] >= 0) alert('Положительное число: ' + arr[i] + ', индекс ' + i);

arr = [1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) alert('Четное число:' + arr[i] + ', индекс ' + i);
```

Для обхода массива используется цикл for.

Подробнее о циклах - https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for

Еще методы для перебора массивов - https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration

Оператор % - возвращает значение остатка при делении. Т.е. если остаток при делении на 2 равен 0, то число четное.

Подробнее об операторах - http://javascript.ru/arithmetic

Comment: Спасибо,это понятно то что в сравнении делать и математические операторы. Не понятно как заставить именно  со ввода в ручную  определенного элемента произвести проверку на положительность.